# How to set the src for each img in a table in VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net

If I wanted to loop through the img src of the following cells uisng a For Each loop and set the src for each of them based on another value (x) can I explicity reference the img src attributes in code, or is it better to embed the table in a control further up the hierarchy. Or maybe this would be better actioned client side with javascript? I have written a basic function to check the value of x as below. Am I on the right lines?

```
    Public Function GetCheckbox(ByVal x As Integer) As String
            Dim checkboxSrc As String = String.Empty
            Dim checked As String = "~/graphics/checkbox-checked.jpg"
            Dim unchecked As String = "~/graphics/checkbox-unchecked.jpg"

            If x = 1 Then
                checkboxSrc = checked
            ElseIf x = 0 Then
                checkboxSrc = unchecked
            End If
            Return checkboxSrc
        End Function


<table id="tblHolisticConcerns" runat="server" border="2" >               
                    <tr id="trPracticalConcerns2" runat="server">                              
                        <td style="width:20%; height:25px; vertical-align:middle"><img id="img2" alt="Holistic Checkbox" runat="server" src="" style="width:16px; height:16px" />&nbsp;Child Care<asp:Literal ID="litChildCare" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
                        <td style="width:20%; height:25px; vertical-align:middle"><img id="img3" alt="Holistic Checkbox" runat="server" src="" style="width:16px; height:16px" />&nbsp;Communication<asp:Literal ID="litCommunication" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
                        <td style="width:20%; height:25px; vertical-align:middle"><img id="img4" alt="Holistic Checkbox" runat="server" src="" style="width:16px; height:16px" />&nbsp;Household Tasks<asp:Literal ID="litHouseholdTasks" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
                        <td style="width:20%; height:25px; vertical-align:middle"><img id="img5" alt="Holistic Checkbox" runat="server" src="" style="width:16px; height:16px" />&nbsp;Housing<asp:Literal ID="litHousing" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
                        <td style="width:20%; height:25px; vertical-align:middle"><img id="img6" alt="Holistic Checkbox" runat="server" src="" style="width:16px; height:16px" />&nbsp;Insurance<asp:Literal ID="litInsurance" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using ASP.NET. Is that correct? How do you know which img tags to set to which graphics? If that info is in a database, you might want to consider using a datagrid instead of a HTML table.

Comment: @tgolisch Yes ASP.NET is correct. There are an equivalent 5 database columns for the above 5 rows which are populated with 0 or 1, and this will dictate which string/path will populate the img src attribute of each cell.

Comment: How are you outputting the table (above)?  Is it raw HTML on the .aspx page or are you outputting it as a string like <%=  %>?  How about the data. Is there only one row or does it vary?  Is it always 5 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, based on your markup you can loop thru all the images like this:

```
For Each oRow As HtmlTableRow In tblHolisticConcerns.Rows

  CType(oRow.Cells(0).Controls(0), HtmlImage).Src = GetCheckbox(Value)

Next
```